# Can I recover my old Windows 7 os

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, recovery

I had a PC preinstalled with Windows 7. Since it wasn't working and the shop owner could not repair it, I bought a new PC preinstalled with Windows 10.
I want to use the old Windows 7 alongside Windows 10. I have a product key of the old Windows 7. Also, I tried to install Windows 7 manually at Microsoft, but it said that my OS was preinstalled, and I should contact my manufacturer for more information.
I would appreciate it if someone helped me get my old Windows 7 I don't need my files or anything.

Comment: If you had a Windows 7 OEM licence then it is not transferable to new hardware.

Comment: There's also the practical consideration that your new machine may not even be able to run Win7.

Comment: There will be No windows 7 drivers for that hardware.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no. You can only install a licensed copy of windows in only one computer.

Microsoft's privacy policy is quite strict about this. When you install windows with a product key in one PC, the installation will be locked there and pass the lifetime there. So to install windows 7 again, you have to purchase a new product key with a windows disk image from online. Or If you like, you can purchase a whole new licensed copy then transfer the old files into new PC.

Comment: This isn't the case if you have a Retail license.  However, since the author's machine came with Windows 7, what you describe is indeed the case for the author.  I am not entirely sure I agree that Microsoft''s privacy policy is what is applicable though.